# How to add some value in data window of trading view?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to extend the supertrend indicator. I added the following code which draws a circle when a trend line is completed and the signal is changed from buy to sell and vice versa

```
plotshape(sellSignal ? up : na, title="Last Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.blue, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal ? dn : na, title="Last Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.gray, transp=0)
```

How to add the value of last circle to data window? It is showing the titles but no values..
[image]

I tried like

```
lastBuy = sellSignal ? up : na
lastBuy := sellSignal ? up : lastBuy
plotchar(lastBuy, "Last Buy 1", "")
```

its showing Last Buy 1 in the data window, but again its empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to know a value when an event happens, you can store that information in a `var` variable. Then use `plotchar()` to display this information in the data window.

Below is an exammple of displaying SMA9's value at a crossover.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var float sma_val_at_co = na

sma_9 = ta.sma(close, 9)
sma_co = ta.crossover(close, sma_9)

plot(sma_9, "SMA 9", color=color.green)
plotshape(sma_co, "SMA Cross", color=color.red)

sma_val_at_co := sma_co ? sma_9 : sma_val_at_co  // Get the value at crossover or keep its old value

plotchar(sma_val_at_co, "SMA value at crossover", "", display=display.data_window)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the updated code, but its still empty. I m still not sure how to preserve the last value.

Comment: Did you define the variables with the `var` keyword? Could you please share a minimal working example?